# Create an HTML list from JSON

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of objects:

[image]

I have a div:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="list-puntate">
  <!-- Insert my list here -->                              
</div>
```

JS

```
var listDiv = document.getElementById('list-puntate');
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.appendChild(listDiv);
for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; ++i) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(data.list[i].puntata);
  ul.appendChild(li);                                 
}
```

I would like to have a result like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="list-puntate">
  <ul>
    <li>values of data.list[i].puntata</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>                              
</div>
```

Comment: `.appendChild()` adds a `Node` to an element. But `data.list[i].puntata` (in `li.appendChild(data.list[i].puntata);`) isn't a `Node` but a string. You could use [`.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) to convert the string to a Node which can then be added with `.appendChild()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do as follows:

```
var listDiv = document.getElementById('list-puntate');
var ul=document.createElement('ul');
for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; ++i) {
      var li=document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = data.list[i].puntata;   // Use innerHTML to set the text
      ul.appendChild(li);                                 
}
listDiv.appendChild(ul);    // Note here
```

Comment: yes it work well, but my array json is a call ajax of data of my DB, i'm updating every second my div "list-puntate" with list from my DB, now every second my list of 10 items is becoming 10,20,30,...etc. There is a way to clear list html after finish "for" cycle ? thank you!

Comment: To remove all `li`'s, just call `ul.innerHTML=''`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var listDiv = document.getElementById('list-puntate');
var ul=document.createElement('ul');
listDiv.appendChild(ul);
for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; ++i) {

  var li=document.createElement('li');
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(data.list[i].puntata);    
  li.appendChild(textnode);
  ul.appendChild(li);                                 
}
```